# Android pdf upload to firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making an app which has a feature to upload a pdf file through the app and another user can also download the uploaded file and use it, so can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: Read about poi library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Server Side or Admin App to upload pdf to Firebase by using Admin Sdk. Then You can use Firebase Storage to upload files then retrieve pdf url from storage and save it to Firebase Database. After that you can retrieve that data and download it from database by using Download Manager.